# How to load Mediawiki 1.28.0 with 1.15.0 data

Tags: mediawiki

I have a Mediawiki setup which is down but I have a backup of the database and all files. I would like to load a new up-to-date freshly, empty installed and running instance of Mediawiki  (1.28.0) with the data from the old instance (1.15.0). Is it possible? What is the procedure?

Regard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install 1.28, replace the database with the dump, run `update.php` and wish yourself luck.

If that doesn't work, your can try installing it under 1.15, then replacing the files with a newer version and running `update.php` (possibly in multiple smaller steps - moving from one LTS release to the next tends to be well-tested).

Comment: Do you mean I must delete 1.28 database and restore 1.15 database and then run update.php?

Comment: Yeah, drop all tables and import the dump. That's identical to how upgrading a working 1.15 wiki to 1.28 would go - you start with the 1.15 DB+files , you replace the files with those from 1.28, you run `update.php` (which does all the necessary database migrations).

Comment: Make sure to properly set up your `LocalSettings.php` though. Your extensions need to be enabled when `update.php` is run, otherwise they can't tell the updater what DB migrations they need.

Comment: It worked. Thanks. I had to manually update the old LocalSettings.php with the new installtion détails. Then command line maintenance/update.php worked. Then I replace the old/updated LocalSettings.php with the new one correctly edited with the new détails.

Comment: It worked for me from 1.17.2 as well. In addition, I had to work around bad SSH setup. To do that:
1. Install 1.28.0, don't put the LocalSettings.php in place yet.
2. Import your database
3. Run the install again (just visit your URL, it will run through install again because it is missing LocalSettings.php).